# saving nested list into database in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have a list of values that having list inside of the model. How to save this data in one go in the database?
I created a model class and converted to JSON and tried to save the data but showing exception
Unhandled Exception:

> DatabaseException(java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer)

```
Future<VendorEventCommitListModel> saveVendorEventCommitList(VendorEventCommitListModel vendorEventCommitList) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    // this will insert the Album object to the DB after converting it to a json
   // int res = await dbClient.rawInsert('INSERT INTO vendor_event_commit_list() VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [userDetailsDBModel.getName,userDetailsDBModel.getEmail,userDetailsDBModel.getUsertype,userDetailsDBModel.getPhone1,userDetailsDBModel.getPhone2,userDetailsDBModel.getGrnder,userDetailsDBModel.getAddress,userDetailsDBModel.getCity,userDetailsDBModel.getState,userDetailsDBModel.getCountry]);
    vendorEventCommitList.eventId = await dbClient.insert('vendor_event_commit_list', vendorEventCommitList.toJson());
    return vendorEventCommitList;
  }
```

Mapper model looks like

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "eventId": eventId,
    "venderEmail": venderEmail,
    "username": username,
    "date": date,
    "eventDateTime": eventDateTime,
    "eventName": eventName,
    "utensils": utensils,
    "hotServe": hotServe,
    "carting": carting,
    "eventAddress": eventAddress,
    "remarks": remarks,
    "Vgccourse": List<dynamic>.from(Vgstr.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "Vgstr": List<dynamic>.from(Vgstr.map((x) => x.toJson())),
}
```

Below is the api response.

```
[{
            "event_id": 2,
            "Vender_Email": null,
            "username": "neenabastin@gmail.com",
            "date": "2019-12-06T11:38:19.7681942+05:30",
            "Event_date_time": "2019-11-06T12:18:35.943",
            "Event_name": "Marriage",
            "Utensils": 0,
            "Hot_serve": 0,
            "Carting": 0,
            "Event_Address": "",
            "Remarks": "",
            "itemdetails": null,
            "Vgccourse": [
                {
                    "Vgccourseitem": "Appam",
                    "Vgccoursecount": 67
                },
                {
                    "Vgccourseitem": "Appam",
                    "Vgccoursecount": 67
                }
            ],
            "Vgstr": [
                {
                    "Vgstritem": "item",
                    "Vgstr_count": 56
                },
                 {
                    "Vgstritem": "item",
                    "Vgstr_count": 56
                },
            ]
    },
    {
            "event_id": 2,
            "Vender_Email": null,
            "username": "neenabastin@gmail.com",
            "date": "2019-12-06T11:38:19.7681942+05:30",
            "Event_date_time": "2019-11-06T12:18:35.943",
            "Event_name": "Marriage",
            "Utensils": 0,
            "Hot_serve": 0,
            "Carting": 0,
            "Event_Address": "",
            "Remarks": "",
            "itemdetails": null,
            "Vgccourse": [
                {
                    "Vgccourseitem": "Appam",
                    "Vgccoursecount": 67
                },
                {
                    "Vgccourseitem": "Appam",
                    "Vgccoursecount": 67
                }
            ],
            "Vgstr": [
                {
                    "Vgstritem": "item",
                    "Vgstr_count": 56
                },
                 {
                    "Vgstritem": "item",
                    "Vgstr_count": 56
                },
            ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily saving the list as JSON object String or you have to create master detail tables

Comment: I didn't get master details tables? Can you explain more?

Comment: @neena you can create 3 table one for events, and the other for Vgccourse,Vgstr,
for each recored in the  events table  there are a multi records for  Vgccourse,Vgstr
after parsing data you have to insert all data in the tables 


or you can create one table by one record and save all JSON String in this recored